# retrieve the history of the contents of globals variables after the execution of the code C

Tags: c, global-variables

I search a tools or a code that allows me to retrieve the history of the contents of globals variables after the execution of a fucntion in C.

I try to use Some tools profiling but it's not work for the langage C

For exemple I have this code :

```
int a =1;
int b =1;
for (i=1;i++;i<4){
    a = a+i;
    b = b*i;
}
```

I want to display after exécution a result or a report like this:

```
 a=1  |  b=1
 a=2  |  b=1
 a=4  |  b=2
 a=7  |  b=6
```

Comment: You need to log the information you want. Use a log file or just print it.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the section named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Unless you actually output the values - either before or after they are changed - then there is no way.   There isn't a way to magically work out the values held by variables after the fact, unless they have been stored or output to a known place in a format that can be interpreted.

Comment: [Duplicate by OP.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55601614/coverage-of-variables-in-c-program)

Comment: This `(i=1;i++;i<4)` does not make sense at all. I should be `(i=1;i<4;i++)`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach, that in most cases is enough, is to output the variables using e.g. `printf` from the `stdio.h` header:

```
int a =1;
int b =1;
for (i=1;i++;i<4){
    printf("%d %d\n", a, b);
    a = a+i;
    b = b*i;
}
printf("%d %d\n", a, b); /* for the last set of values */
```

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do the follwing:

```
#include "stdio.h"

int a = 1;
int b = 1;

#if DEBUG_HISTORY
int * pa = &a;
int * pb = &b;

#define a printf("a = %d\n", a); (*pa)
#define b printf("b = %d\n", b); (*pb)
#endif

int main()
{
  int i;

  for (i=1; i<4; i++)
  {
    a += i;
    b *= i;
  }
}
```

Compile with option `-DDEBUG_HISTORY` and get:

```
a = 1
b = 1
a = 2
b = 1
a = 4
b = 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply,
I tested your solution on eclipse but I did not find where are the traces of the result of the history